# What should Github .gitignore file for Spring Framework be?

Tags: spring, eclipse, github

I have installed a spring framework (java) application in my github account. but the project is showing JavaScript in the project language even though the project is written in java. How should my .gitignore file be?
P.s: I created project in Eclipce.

Comment: Where is the programming language JavaScript displayed? On the GitHub project web site? (GitHub tries to determine the used programming language based on the content, which is not always 100% successful.)

Comment: @howlger Yes, on the github project website? What display convert Javascript to Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **automatic language detection** fails in a GitHub repository, the language for specific files can be specified/**overridden via the `.gitattributes`** file (and not via the [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file).

For details see GitHub Help and the GitHub Linguist project:

[GitHub Help - About repository languages:](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/)

> **The files and directories within a repository determine the languages**
>   that make up the repository. [...]
>
> GitHub uses the open source [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to determine file
>   languages for syntax highlighting and repository statistics.

[GitHub - Linguist - Troubleshooting:](https://github.com/github/linguist#troubleshooting)

> 3. [...] You can also use the [**manual overrides**](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) feature to correctly classify them in your repository.

[GitHub - Linguist - Overrides:](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides)

> Add a **`.gitattributes` file** to your project and use standard git-style
>   path matchers for the files you want to override using the
>   `linguist-documentation`, **`linguist-language`**, `linguist-vendored`,
>   `linguist-generated` and `linguist-detectable` attributes.
>   `.gitattributes` will be used to determine language statistics and
>   will be used to syntax highlight files. [...]
>
> ```
> $ cat .gitattributes
> *.rb linguist-language=Java
> ```